# Making a ring mouth

Tags: modeling, bezier-curves

I am trying to make a ring smiley mouth, as seen in the image below:

[image]

And here is what I have so far:

[image]

I've made a circle, converted it to a curve, and applied bevel.
In Edit Mode, I moved the selected vertices a bit down to make a smile.

But the problems I have right now are:

1. The top and bottom parts are uneven; the top lip and the bottom lip have different sizes, the bottom one is slightly bigger.
2. There are wrinkles on both sides of the corner.

I want to make that clean even curve like in the first image. Are there any other ways you guys can recommend?

Comment: It's always good to note the source of an image if it isn't (obvious that it's) made by yourself. Is it also the case that the curve is not a complete loop? There seems to be a connection missing in the upper left corner..

Comment: Yes, I just realised, thats another problem. I tried connecting those two vertices by pressing F but I get an error message saying "cannot make segment". I dont get it because I only converted a full circle mesh to curve

Comment: I don't think the lack of connection is a problem if it was a converted mesh.  If you look in *Active Spline* it will have *Cyclic U* checked, which makes it continuous.

Answer (score 2):

You can create a bezier circle (4 vertices), give it a *Bevel Depth*, and tweak the *Resolution* values, here I've tried a *Shape Resolution* and a *Bevel Resolution* of 12. Give it a *Subdivision Surface* modifier and it will fix the bad shading. It looks like to avoid wrinkles you need to rotate and play with the vertices scale a bit, I'm not sure you can avoid them with all the shapes it will take. To animate, hook to empties of bones. You can play with the thickness of each vertex with its *Radius* value (N panel or <kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>S</kbd>):

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Try increasing the *Bevel Resolution* further.  Unfortunately 32 is the maximum and even manual input won't go any higher.

[image]